# How to write hash key and value pairs into MongoDB documents as field values in Perl?

Tags: perl, mongodb

```
my %Hash= (2012=> 1, 1982=>12, 2010=>0);
```

The has key and values need to be all on the same field name 'time' like an array

```
$mycollection->insert(
                     {
                         'field1' => $var1;
                         'field2' => $var2;
                          #right here I need to know how to add above hash key and values
                          # like below  
                          #'time': ["2012.1","1982.12","2010.0"]   
                     }
                   );
```

Any suggestions or ideas will be apprecieated. This can probably accomplished by doing series of update statements but I would like to accomplish this with one insert statement due to my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your %Hash variable is something like this:

```
my %Hash= (2012=> 1, 1982=>12, 2010=>0);
```

So your array "time" is build this way:

```
my @time = map { $_ . "." . $Hash{$_} } keys %Hash;
```

and finally:

```
$mycollection->insert({
   'field1' => $var1,
   'field2' => $var2,
   'time' => \@time   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Sorry about my lazy representation of my hash. It was not meant to be code to be compiled. That was me trying to write quick to get my idea across.